# Adding JSON customers_contacts into customers table

Tags: mysql, json

Using the classicmodels database you installed in Module 1 and your MySQL Workbench, add a JSON field named “customers_contacts” to the customers table with the following keys:

> customerNumber,
>   contactLastName, and
>   contactFirstName.
>   Write a SQL statement to insert at least three values for the “customers_contacts” field. Use data from the customers table.

```
INSERT INTO customers(customers_contacts)

Values(

'{"customerNumber" : 103, "customerLastName" : "Schmitt", "customerFirstName" : "Carine"}'

);
```

So I use ALTER TABLE customers ADD COLUMN customers_contacts json; - which works to create the column.

But when I go to add the values such as:

```
INSERT INTO customers(customers_contacts)

Values(

'{"customerNumber" : 103, "customerLastName" : "Schmitt", "customerFirstName" : "Carine"}'

);
```

I get the error code 1364: Field 'customerNumber' doesn't have a default value.

I am using mysql 5.7 and mysql workbench. A

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ba29f079ee7e4d0333434e62654ac11c).

Comment: It seems as though you're supposed to parse the json prior to insertion, but I guess this was covered in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually your dealing with field is 'customerNumber' when your inserting new json value in  'customers_contacts' the 'customerNumber' has no default value .alter the table and set a default value for customer number like '0000000000'.save the changes and insert the json value. 
ex :
what you are trying do is this

1. PK    |CustomerNumber    |customers_contacts |
2. 1        1234567890       {"some":" json value"}
3. 2          null           {"some":"jsonvalue"}

since your CustomerNumber  field cannot be null you have to set default value or remove not null